# Shell Script for moving files to a specific Folder

Tags: bash, scripting

perhaps someone can point me in the right direction:
I want to move certain files which are named on a specific type (e.g. file%AA) to the mirrored place in my archive.
So for example i have the following:

```
livefolder/folder1/file%AA.csv
```

and want to move it to

```
archivefolder/folder1/file%AA.csv
```

When the archive folder does not exist, it should be created.
How can i achive this?
At the moment i am stuck with this:

```
find /livefolder/folder1/ -type d  \( -name '*%AA' \) -exec mv {} /archivefolder/folder1/ +
```

But then i would need to do this for every subfolder which exist. Is there a way to do this recursevily for all subfolders?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to do this with `rsync`.

Comment: Have a look at `rsync`, maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by Barmer and Renaud, you can use the [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). It will create the `subdirectories` in the path if it does not exist when you use `--relative` option. But you need to have the parent directory present (unfortunately, in your case `archivefolder`). Anyways, you can create it with `mkdir -p` (`-p` will only create a directory if it does not exist).

`rsync` command will look like this:

```
rsync -a --relative livefolder/./folder1/file%AA.csv archivefolder
```

`relative` will set the path in `destination` with respect to the `source` you have provided.

i.e it will be equal to

```
rsync [options] livefolder/folder1/file%AA.csv archivefolder/folder1/file%AA.csv
```

We should use `.` after `livefolder` inside the source path in rsync command (`rsync -a --relative livefolder/./folder1/file%AA.csv`). This means that in the destination path given, rsync will copy in the format `/folder1/file%AA.csv` (i.e follow the hierarchy mentioned after `.` in the source). Hence, this will create `folder1/file%AA.csv` inside `archivefolder`.

Comment: Well this specific only works when the File ist called file%AA.csv ?
How to do it with every file which has %AA in its name?

Comment: You can leave the filename and add only the directory path.

Comment: Thanks very much. Got it working with
`rsync -am --relative --include='*%A*' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /livefolder/./ /share/archivefolder/`